# "Class 'Nexmo\\Laravel\\Facades\\Nexmo' not found" Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport, vonage

I am trying to send an sms once a user signs up but it keep getting:

`"Class 'Nexmo\\Laravel\\Facades\\Nexmo' not found"`

I have this at the top of my controller file:

`use Nexmo\Laravel\Facades\Nexmo;`

I also have this in my `config/app.php` file

`'Nexmo' => Nexmo\Laravel\Facades\Nexmo::class,`

Im still getting an error, does anyone or has the same problem. I know its a class type error but why if I have added the right class and im using it appropriately.

Also, here is my code implementation:

```
Nexmo::message()->send([
    'to' => '1122334455', //not actually using this number
    'from' => 'Test',
    'text' => 'Hey, test this digit code',
    'text' => $request->user()->activation_token
]);
```

Update 1:
I have done `php artisan vendor:publish` and published the nexmo config file but it sill gives the error above.

Comment: I think you have a typo `Facades` should be `Facade` from the github repo: `use Nexmo\Laravel\Facade\Nexmo`

Answer (score 0):

Add Nexmo\Laravel\NexmoServiceProvider to the providers array in your config/app.php:

```
   'providers' => [
    // Other service providers...

    Nexmo\Laravel\NexmoServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for answers/suggestions

Some reason it is working now? I did all the suggestions/answers and it did not work, did some other stuff (not working on this) and it suddenly works?

Thanks guys :)

If I found out what I did to make it work I will update this answer.

Found the answer:
Found out when I run `php artisan vendor:publish` it gives a list to publish or something and i'm guessing I did not do the one that specifically publishes Nexmo. Still should've worked though because I did the one that will publish everything. Anyways that published the Nexmo file in `config` folder. Somehow that is what made everything else work, that and probably a combination of answer/suggestions

Anyways thanks guys for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the **Nexmo** documentation did not mention about to use with **Laravel** but there are as a additional package you need to use if you used with **Laravel**.

There are are a simple solution.You need to install a additional package that already provide by **Nextmo** to use with **Laravel**.Just install below one.I hope this will help u.

```
composer require nexmo/laravel
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
            $nexmo = app('Nexmo\Client');

                $nexmo->message()->send([
                    'to' => 'yournumber',
                    'from' => 'yournumber',
                    'text' => "message"
                ]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).